# как вынести картинки за блок, чтобы они были по ширине экрана HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, контейнеры, блок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]подскажите пожалуйста, как вынести картинки за блок, чтобы они были по ширине экрана?вот пример страницы[image: ФОТО]

Comment: добавьте ваш пример

Comment: Добавил) я сначала думал через грид сетку... но не получилось

Comment: также добавил код штмл

Comment: ctrl+m нажмите, и добавьте html css,